# What does the phrase "to die for good" mean?

Tags: phrases

Earlier I saw a new web clip to the vampire diaries season 6 episode 7, where Alarick says:

> If you kill me, I am dead for good this time.

Please, explain to me what this means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"[For good](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+good)" means **irrevocably**, **for ever**. In this context, it means Alarick would not be able to resurrect (come back to life) as (I presume) he usually does.

> - forever; permanently. I finally left home for good. They tried to repair it many times before they fixed it for good. (from TFD)

(Disclaimer: I haven't watched the series in a long time, and have no idea who Alarick is).

Comment: "For good" *sometimes* means **irrevocably, for ever**.  Other times it means **to positive effect**.  Eg, maybe the series will improve with Alarick dead?

Comment: Thank you really much. :)) Btw, Alarick actually appears in 1st season, so you must've remembered him.

Comment: @jwpat7: Haha... yes, there is certainly the non-idiomatic meaning, too (e.g. in *He is a powerful force for good*)... but I can't access it in OP's sentence.

Comment: I must have *seen* him, then. But I certainly don't *remember* him. Also, you can't say *really much*, use *very much* instead. You're welcome!

Comment: @Amadan, yeah, you're right. thx, again :)